# Python Zeep: How to get success status on job competition

Tags: python, database, oracle, soap, zeep

I have job which loads data to Oracle database.
I have published that job as a web service and I am triggering that job using python.

After running job I am getting return code , error code, PID and CID,
But data in the table loads after minutes depending on the data, is there any way to get response only after data loads completed in the table.

```
wsdl = 'link' 
client = Client(wsdl, transport=transport)
client.service.Logon('username','password','server','secEnterprise')
client_admin = client.bind('DataServices_Server', 'Batch_Jobs')
client_admin.Job_Name() # Trigger the Job
```